# Keypress event to web page not working from iframe

Tags: javascript, html, keypress

I created a web page using html and javascript. Used iframe inside the page and assigned keypress event to the window [like](http://jsbin.com/vuvowuhaye/1/edit?html,js,output),

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Keypress Event test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function onKeyPress(e){alert(e.keyCode);}
      window.addEventListener("keypress", onKeyPress);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Helow! Welcome!</h1>
    <iframe src="..." />
  </body>
</html>
```

On key press the alert is working fine. after click iframe and press key the function is not working.
How can bring keypress event from iframe?

Comment: FYI: On keypress the alert is NOT working after the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

If you place an iFrames on a page, then the browser will create a window object for the page, and one for each iFrame.

I suspect this is the cause of this problem, since your code does not explicitly say which window object to attach the `keypress` event to.